# Why is my cursor count 0?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to SQLite and I am building an application to suggest recipes based on ingredients selection but while I am checking if my database contains any records, it does not shows any records and displays cursor count as 0.
I am getting the column count as 3 but i am not getting the row count.
Please help.

This is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    public final static String DATABASE_NAME = "gobbled.db";
    public final static String TABLE1 = "ingredients";
    public final static String TABLE2 = "dishes";
    public final static String TABLE3 = "recipe";
    public final static String COLUMN_1_1 = "ing_id";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id INT(4) PRIMARY KEY, ing_name VARCHAR, ing_category VARCHAR)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE2 + "(dish_id INT(4) PRIMARY KEY, dish_name VARCHAR, dish_recipe VARCHAR)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE3 + "(dish_id INT(4) , ing_id INT(4))");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (1, 'Onion', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (2, 'Garlic', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (3, 'Tomato', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (4, 'Potato', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (5, 'Carrot', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (6, 'Broccoli', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (7, 'Corn', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (8, 'Spinach', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (9, 'Mushroom', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (10, 'GreenBeans', 'Vegetable')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (11, 'Butter', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (12, 'Egg', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (13, 'Milk', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (14, 'Yogurt', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (15, 'Cream', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (16, 'Mozarella', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (17, 'Cheddar', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (18, 'WhippedCream', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (19, 'Buttermilk', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (20, 'CottageCheese', 'Dairy')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (21, 'Lemon', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (22, 'Apple', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (23, 'Banana', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (24, 'Strawberry', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (25, 'Orange', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (26, 'Pineapple', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (27, 'Coconut', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (28, 'Grape', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (29, 'Guava', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (30, 'Mango', 'Fruits')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (31, 'Rice', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (32, 'Pasta', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (33, 'Flour', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (34, 'Bread', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (35, 'BreadCrumbs', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (36, 'BakingSoda', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (37, 'BakingPowder', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (38, 'Yeast', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (39, 'Buiscuits', 'Baking & Grains')");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE1 + "(ing_id, ing_name, ing_category) VALUES (40, 'Cornflour', 'Baking & Grains')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

This is my cursor code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class main_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper mydb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    logo.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);
    TextView logotext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logotext);
    logotext.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(500);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setTranslationX(50f);
    b1.animate().translationXBy(-50f).setDuration(1000);
    Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setTranslationX(50f);
    b2.animate().translationXBy(-50f).setDuration(1500);
    Button b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setTranslationX(50f);
    b3.animate().translationXBy(-50f).setDuration(2000);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t1.setTranslationX(-50f);
    t1.animate().translationXBy(50f).setDuration(500);
}
public void ingredientapp(View view)
{
    String name = mydb.getDatabaseName();
    Log.i("info", name);
    Log.i("Info","Button Pressed");
    Cursor c = mydb.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ingredients", null);
    int n = c.getCount();
    Log.i("info", Integer.toString(n));
    startActivity(new Intent(main_Screen.this,Main2Activity.class));
}
public void recipeapp(View view)
{

    Log.i("Info","Button Pressed");
    startActivity(new Intent(main_Screen.this,Main3Activity.class));
}
public void recommendapp(View view)
{
    Log.i("Info","Button Pressed");
    startActivity(new Intent(main_Screen.this,Main4Activity.class));
}
```

}

It is displaying the database name and the "Button Pressed" meassage but displaying the count as 0. Why?
I have a project . Please suggest.

Comment: By the way, your database structure is poorly designed. Please learn about **normalization**. You are missing a `Categories` table, **at least**.

Comment: I am just checking if the database works, I obviously need to think of it.

Comment: I tried it, not working. is the cursor code correct?. i am running it on a button click

Comment: show the code from where you initializing DatabaseHelper

Comment: This is my entire code with the cursor code which runs on a method on buttonclick

Comment: @AyushSaxena did you try removing line **db = this.getWritableDatabase();** from onCreate ?

Comment: Yes i did, still same, i think there is a problem while inserting records because i am getting the column count as 3 but not the row count.

Comment: @AyushSaxena you also had to do fresh install after making the changes. Just uninstall the app after making the changes and then rerun app.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma yeah it worked, thanks

Comment: @AyushSaxena awesome, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line,

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Then you should get count as 40. `getWriteableDatabase` is not supposed to be called in `onCreate`. The `db` parameter is already the writeable database passed to the `onCreate` method.

Comment: i know nothing, did this first time after watching tutorials, please elaborate

Comment: I tried your full code with removing that line and it worked. You might have corrupted the db and may need to uninstall as other answer suggested. Can you try it?

Comment: Yeah, it woeked. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate()` is incorrect. You cannot call `getWritableDatabase()` there since it would trigger `onCreate()` recursively and throw an exception.

Since you're not seeing that exception, this version of `onCreate()` with the inserts is not executed at all. I guess you've edited it after running an earlier version of your app that already created the database for you. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Remove the recursive `getWritableDatabase()` call and use the `SQLiteDatabase` given you as a parameter. You can uninstall and reinstall your app then to recreate the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the app from the device/emulator (so that the db will be deleted)
2. Remove `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` from `onCreate()`
3. Run the app again (now `onCreate()` will be called again)

If the db exists `onCreate()` is not invoked